# In Laravel 5.8, How do I setup a polymorphic relationship between a Model and a package Model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a package model named `Company\Contact\Models\Contact`

I have a local model named `App\Models\MenuItem`

Menu item is a polymorphic table with:

```
id
menuable_id  
menuable_type
```

When I use it on local models like `\App\Models\Page` it works fine. When I call the `menuable` relationship in my `MenuItem` model, this one:

```
public function menuable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

`$menuitem->menuable` it gives me an instance of the page model, great, perfect. But when I do this on any package model it is `null`.

I tried binding my model:

```
$this->app->bind('Company\Contact\Models\Contact', function () {
    return new Contact;
});
```

But that didn't work.

I then tried mapping it in the `AppServiceProvider` boot:

```
use Company\Contact\Models\Contact; // This does dump an instance of the contact model. 

Relation::morphMap([
    'Company\Contact\Models\Contact' => Contact::class,
]);
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Have you logged the executed queries?

Comment: I will try this now.

Comment: Try to make a local modal and extend the package model in it. Then, make relations between local models.

Comment: The way I have done it in the past is to extend the model within my own applications namespace and then use that Model instead of the one directly from the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the packages model from within your own applications codebase. Create a new **Contact** class within your `App/Models` directory:.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Company\Contact\Models\Contact as CompanyContact;

class Contact extends CompanyContact
{
  // your polymorphic relationship methods
}
```

Now you can use the `App\ModelContact` model in your application instead of the packages model.

Comment: Thank you! This does work but I'm hoping to not have to create App\ModelContact because a package may or may not be part of my codebase. But I guess that if the package isn't in use App\ModelContact will not be called anyways. As I type this I think this is the right solution. I will test further. Thanks again!